# MySQL connectivity in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

How can I do MySQL connectivity in Visual Studio Express 2012 as I want to generate ado.net entity framework model from my mysql i have studied this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/10476.instalando-mysql-connector-no-visual-studio-2011-beta.aspx) and type the following command on command window:

`md PastaExtraidos`

and then type the following command

`msiexec/ sqlyog502/ qb TARGETDIR= D: \ PastaExtraidos`

but i m unable to find any file in  this target directory

Comment: at the v least there shouldn't be a space between 'D:\' and the 'Pastaextraidos' text.

Answer (score 0):

Use Connector/NET, in the version 6.6 is compatible with VS2012, from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.6.html.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it is specified in the question that @iProgrammer is working on an Express version of Visual Studio in which Connector/NET is not supported due to some legal constraints [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904823/how-to-add-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio-2012-express-for-web/16177310#16177310).