# how to add mysql data source in visual studio 2012 express for web

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector, connector-net

i'm trying to add mysql connection to my asp.net mvc 4 projects but i dont see it on the data source window.

after installing visual studio 2012 express for web i added mysql Connector/Net through nuget. i wanted to add new connection to mysql db but i did see mysql data source on the data source window list. after a search i realized that i have v6.6.4 and it supported from 6.6.5 so i uninstalled it from nuget and install 6.6.5 from mysql website(a complete install). it didnt helped.. i also tried to uninstall and reinstall it but it didnt change a thing.

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that its an express version.
i installed a non express version and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Connector/NET thru nuget will not install any of the visual studio integration stuff, for that you will need to run the Connector/NET installer (available at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

However due to legal constraints from Microsoft, integration with Visual Studio express editions is not possible (you'll need a non express version of visual studio).